# Want to open the url of a URL field in a visualforce page using iframe

Tags: visualforce, url, iframe

I am having a custom URL field on task. I dont want to show my users the URL when I click on the field.I have created a visulaforce page that have buttons on clicking whom the URL should open in an iframe.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this as Javascript action for the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onClick()
  {
    document.getElementById('myIframe').src = 'https://www.Salesforce.com';
  }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Change site" onClick="onClick()" />
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://salesforce.stackexchange.com"></iframe>
```